# Google App Engine Launcher ImportError after upgrade

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I upgraded GAE Launcher for Windows 1.8.0. Now when I try to run any program (python2.7) I get the following Import Error in the app engine launcher log:

```
from email.utils import (
ImportError: No module named email.utils
2013-05-22 10:25:12 (Process exited with code 1)
```

I have the latest version of App Engine, plugin for eclipse, pydev etc. I have all the libraries imported in my application's preferences. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with Windows 64 bit version of some software and 32 bit version of python. Once I uninstalled the 32 bit version of Python 2.7.2 and installed the 64 bit version everything worked fine.