# Google App Engine ImportError For Hello World

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have been using GAE with Python 2.7 for a few months and after upgrading to 1.8.4 I can no longer load any project (including the generic helloworld project from Google). Every project that was working fine produces the following:

**from email.utils import (
ImportError: No module named email.utils
2013-09-10 21:55:00 (Process exited with code 1)**

This happened after I upgraded the GAE SDK. I noticed one other person 
[Google App Engine Launcher ImportError after upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698203/google-app-engine-launcher-importerror-after-upgrade) had the same problem and solved it by changing Python 2.7 from 32 bits to 64 bits. The problem is I already have Python 2.7 64 bits installed. I have re-installed the older version GAE 1.7.7 to see if the problem would go away, but it persists.

I have been using Aptana Studio 3 with Pydev, but for my latest test simply copied the Google helloworld.py and app.yaml and tried it without Aptana at all. Same problem. At this point I am stumped as to what to try next. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yogi Berra said, "It's deja vu all over again". I solved my own problem just like the previous poster. After upgrading both Python and GAE with the latest minor bug fix editions all is well.